# Replacing fetched results when returning 0 from DB

Tags: php, mysql

When fetching DB I am getting results and everything works to the point where I am getting a price from DB, which is also works, but what I really need to have is if price returned 0 than that "0" should be replace with "P.O.D" instead.

Any help is appreciated.

here is my query code:

```
 $samples = "SELECT * FROM materials, category_price WHERE materials.type = :cat AND materials.supplier = '$supplier' AND materials.category_id = category_price.category_id";
$res = $db->prepare($samples);
$res->execute(array(':cat' => $category));
$count = $res->rowCount();
if($count > 0)
echo "
<section class=\"border mar_t_40\">
"; 
while ($row = $res -> fetch()){
    $postimggranite = $row[image];
    $postidgranite = $row[id];
    $postname = $row[mat_name];
    $folder = $row[type];
    $folder = strtolower($folder);
    $supplier = strtolower($supplier);
    $category_id = $row[category_id];
    $price = ("£ ".$row[price]);


print<<<END
<span class="grid white_back mar_l_30">
<h3>$price</h3>
<a class="fancybox" href="$img_path/$folder/$supplier/large/$postimggranite" rel="group[$postidgranite]" title="$postname"><img alt="$row[name]" src="$img_path/$folder/$supplier/small/$postimggranite" width="100" height="100">$postname</a>
</span>
END;

}
echo "<div class=\"clearfloat\"></div></section>";
```

Comment: So how have you tried to do this? Are you looking for a DB query solution or a PHP code solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514091/how-should-boolean-expressions-be-written-in-php).

This is the expression you are looking for.

```
$price = ($row[price] === 0) ? "P.O.D." : ("£ ".$row[price]);
```

Edit: Side note: I use `=== 0` because of the problem that is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string).

Comment: works. sweet, my mistake was that I have been placing "!" instead of "?".

Answer (score 2):

You can change your query to something like:

```
SELECT some_fields, IF(price=0, 'P.O.D', price) AS price FROM materials, category_price WHERE materials.type = :cat AND materials.supplier = '$supplier' AND materials.category_id = category_price.category_id
```

But why not handle the condition within PHP?

Answer (score 0):

several ideas come to mind, one is the `ternary` operator:

```
$price = ($row[price] == 0 ? 'P.O.D' : '£ ' . $row[price]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$price = (empty($row[price]) ? "P.O.D" : "£ " . $row[price]);
```